# RabbitMQ "Error: Failed to initialize erlang distribution" when trying to change password

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm trying to follow the [RabbitMQ "Hello World" tutorial for Python](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html), but the line

```
import pika
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
```

is giving rise to a `pika.exceptions.ProbableAuthenticationError`. I've read that a possible way to solve this is by changing the password for the `guest` user. So at the command line, I tried

```
rabbitmqctl change_password guest newpass
```

but this yields the error

```
Error: Failed to initialize erlang distribution: {{shutdown,
                                                   {failed_to_start_child,
                                                    net_kernel,
                                                    {'EXIT',nodistribution}}},
                                                  {child,undefined,
                                                   net_sup_dynamic,
                                                   {erl_distribution,
                                                    start_link,
                                                    [['rabbitmq-cli-96',
                                                      shortnames]]},
                                                   permanent,1000,supervisor,
                                                   [erl_distribution]}}.

Only root or rabbitmq should run rabbitmqctl
```

Any ideas what is causing these errors?

Comment: `Only root or rabbitmq should run rabbitmqctl` Did you try using root ?

Comment: Yes, with `sudo` I get the same error, only without the "Only root" message.

Comment: Open a terminal and try to execute `erl -sname test_node`.  I think you have some problem with the Erlang installation